# How to display more number of array results in a single array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, jsonresult

I have two tables: login`and`follow`.

- Table name: `login`
  Fields: `id,email,username,imageurl`
- Table name: `follow`
  Fields: `id:user_id:follow_id`

It's like a Twitter follower's concept. I want to get the details of `myfollower` name and also `myfollower`'s following person's name.

For that I have written the coding as like below.

```
public function follw ()
{
    if( $this->input->get("userid")  )

     {          

    extract($this->input->get()); 

    $followers_list = array();

    $follower = array();

    $query = $this->db->query('select follow_id from follow where user_id = '.$userid.'')->result();

    foreach($query as $row)

    { 
        $follower['follower_id'] = $row->follow_id;

        if($follower['follower_id'] == "")
        {
            echo "hi";
        }

        else
            {
        $query3 = $this->db->query('select username from login where id = '.$follower['follower_id'].'')->result();

        foreach($query3 as $row3)

            {
                $follower['followuser'] = $row3->username;
            }

        $query1 = $this->db->query('select follow_id from follow where user_id = '.$follower['follower_id'].'')->result();

        foreach($query1 as $row1)

            {
                $follower['follow_id'] = $row1->follow_id;

            if($follower['follow_id'] == "")

            {
                echo "jeeva";
                }


            else
            {
        $query2 = $this->db->query('select username from login where id = '.$follower['follow_id'].'')->result();

        foreach($query2 as $row2)

            {
                $follower['username'] = $row2->username;


            }

            }//second for each in else loop
            }//first foreach in else loop

            }//main else
        $followers_list[] = $follower;

        }

        $str = json_encode($followers_list);
    echo stripslashes($str);
}

else
{
    echo '[{"status":"Failure  - Error Occured - Not Enough Details provided"}]';

    }
}
```

I get the output like this:

```
[{"follower_id":"12","followuser":"janmejoy","follow_id":"24","username":"sarvana"},{"follower_id":"10","followuser":"jeeva","follow_id":"23","username":"selva"},{"follower_id":"6","followuser":"raj","follow_id":"17","username":"jeeva"},{"follower_id":"23","followuser":"selva","follow_id":"22","username":"guru"}]
```

This output displays `myfollower`'s name and `myfollower`'s following person name, but the problem is it displays only one member of `myfollower`'s following person name.

However, I want to the output like this:

```
[{"follower_id":"12","followuser":"janmejoy",{"follow_id":"24","username":"sarvana",follow_id":"13","username":"jai",follow_id":"9","username":"raj"}},{"follower_id":"10","followuser":"jeeva","follow_id":"23","username":"selva"},{"follower_id":"6","followuser":"raj","follow_id":"17","username":"jeeva"},{"follower_id":"23","followuser":"selva","follow_id":"22","username":"guru"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

> [{"follower_id":"12","followuser":"janmejoy",{"follow_id":"24","username":"sarvana",follow_id":"13","username":"jai",follow_id":"9","username":"raj"}},{"follower_id":"10","followuser":"jeeva","follow_id":"23","username":"selva"},{"follower_id":"6","followuser":"raj","follow_id":"17","username":"jeeva"},{"follower_id":"23","followuser":"selva","follow_id":"22","username":"guru"}]

This code is invalid JSON variable. i can't solve this question for you. Please update your question.